# Natural Deduction with Identity

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am confused on how to deal with identities in natural deduction proofs with predicate logic.
More specifically, how would one go about solving this?

```
∀x(Fx → x = a)
     ¬Ga
---------------
 ∀x(Gx → ¬Fx)
```

The idenity rules I have are:

```
| c = c    =I
```

and

```
m | c = d
n | Ac
  | Ad     =E m,n
```

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Assume $Gy$. Assume $Fy$. Then $y=a$, so $Ga$, contradiction. Thus $\lnot Fy$. Conclude $\forall x(Gx\to\lnot Fx)$. I'll leave it to you to translate this proof sketch into your formal natural deduction system.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you so much for the help! I feel stupid for not seeing this on my own lol.